# Hibernate ignores milliseconds in query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have Spring Boot with JPA application, which uses Spring specification to build select statement with time including milliseconds. I need to be able to find data between two time ranges accounting for milliseconds.

Database PostgreSQL with field type as time. Hibernate entity field type is LocalTime. As an example, when I pass time range 09:00:01.000 and 09:00:00.203 I can see records which are earlier in time than 09:00:00.203. This tells me something ignores 203 and goes to 09:00:00.

When I run the app SqlStatementLogger shows me proper SQL and parameters, like below.

```
and quoteentit0_.action_time<=? 
and quoteentit0_.action_time>=? 

binding parameter [3] as [TIME] - [09:00:01]
binding parameter [4] as [TIME] - [09:00:00.203]
```

If I take generated statement and parameters from the logs and run via psql like below I get correct results.

```
and quoteentit0_.action_time<='09:00:01.000' 
and quoteentit0_.action_time>='09:00:00.203'
```

Where is my issue? Thanks

**Update**
After debugging Hibernate code I found LocalTime type is mapped to Hibernate TimeTypeDescriptor class, which uses java.sql.Time class, know not to store milliseconds. Therefore, actual parameter value bound is 09:00:00. I am thinking to use LocalDateTime class, which I think, will be mapped to Hibernate's TimestampTypeDescriptor class which uses java.sql.Timestamp capable of storing milliseconds. However, this is suboptimal as database field is of time type and I don't what to do with date portion.

Comment: I manually built select statement, ran it with below code and got correct results.

`entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Entity.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I wound up implementing class of Hibernate UserType interface and implementing getting and setting local time as below.

```
  @Override
  public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.TIME };
  }

  @Override
  public Class returnedClass() {
    return LocalTime.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    final var time = rs.getString(names[0]);
    if (rs.wasNull()) return null;
    return LocalTime.parse(time);
  }

  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (Objects.isNull(value)) {
      st.setNull(index, Types.TIME);
    } else {
      st.setObject(index, value, Types.TIME);
    }
  }
```